# JS - apply global function to all select boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 200+ select boxes, each individually named and with Yes / No / NA as answer options, and now would like to have the background of the `<option value="No>` option highlighted in red once it is selected.

This works fine via the onchange attribute when adding it to the specific select box, however since I have 200 of those, I do not want to apply this code one by one, but rather apply a global JS function to all `<select>` boxes, which is where I am stuck. How can I address all select boxes with one JS function?

Javascript:

```
  $('select').on('change', function () {
      $(this).focus();
      $(this).select();
      $(this).className = this.options[this.selectedIndex].className;
  });
```

CSS:

```
.green{ background-color:green; }
.red{ background-color:red; }
```

HTML:

```
  <select id="boh_corridor" name="boh_corridor">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Yes" class="green">Yes</option>
    <option value="No" class="red">No</option>
  </select>
```

EDIT: to be exact, the problem is that the option is not highlighted in either red or green at the moment, hence I am suspecting that the function is not being applied. The goal is to have the option highlighted in red/green when selected and while being selected from the dropdown menu.

Comment: Other than `$(this).className =` being wrong (either use `this` or `css`, but not `$(this)` and `className`), your code *does* attach a handler to all `select` boxes that does what you describe. What's the question, exactly?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the options are not highlighted, neither while I am selecting them nor after they were selected, hence I suspect a problem while applying the JS function.

Comment: *"the problem is that the option is not highlighted in either red or green at the moment, hence I am suspecting that the function is not being applied"* There's no reason to *suspect* anything; use the fully-featured debugger built into your browser to find out.

Comment: Just on a side note, it could be worth looking at [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for your use case. Like you have written it currently, there will be an event bound to each select. If you write it like this: `$("body").on("change", "select" function(){ ... })` there will only be one event listener on the body (or what ever parent element) that will delegate the event for each select.

Comment: @NicoO: And on a similar side note: Although you can indeed use event delegation with `change` when using jQuery, it's worth noting that `change` doesn't natively bubble and so can't natively be used with event delegation. Just for any readers who aren't using jQuery. :-) (They [they "patch" `change`](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events); I've always meant to look and see *how*...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thats really interesting, thank you :) I guess you miss a lot information if you blindly rely on a framework and rarely step back and look behind the scenes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

1. jQuery objects don't have a `className` property; DOM elements do. Instead of

   ```
   $(this).className = ...
   ```

   use

   ```
   this.className = ...
   ```
2. Your code hooks the `change` event on `select` elements that exist **as of when that code runs**. So you need to be sure they exist prior to running that code. You can do that by ensuring your `script` tag is at the end of the document, just prior to the closing `</body>` tag; or by using jQuery's `ready` callback. Alternately, you can use event delegation (covered later).

Example expecting that the `script` tag will be at the end of the document (which is where Stack Snippets put it), which is best practice:

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {
  $(this).focus();
  $(this).select();
  this.className = this.options[this.selectedIndex].className;
});
```

```css
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<select id="boh_corridor" name="boh_corridor">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="Yes" class="green">Yes</option>
  <option value="No" class="red">No</option>
</select>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you don't control where your `script` tags go or prefer to do something else, using jQuery's `ready`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // ...the code here...
});
```

Another option is *event delegation*. Although `change` doesn't natively bubble, jQuery makes it bubble, and so you can do this:

```
$(document).on("change", "select", function() {
      $(this).focus();
      $(this).select();
      this.className = this.options[this.selectedIndex].className;
});
```

Then it doesn't matter whether the `select` elements exist or not when you run that code; the event handler is on `document`, not the individual `select`s. So it doesn't matter where the `script` tag is, and you don't need `ready`.

Example:

```js
$(document).on('change', 'select', function() {
  $(this).focus();
  $(this).select();
  this.className = this.options[this.selectedIndex].className;
});
```

```css
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<select id="boh_corridor" name="boh_corridor">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="Yes" class="green">Yes</option>
  <option value="No" class="red">No</option>
</select>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Side note: You can use *chaining* with jQuery objects, rather than repeatedly calling `$()`: `$(this).focus().select();`

Comment: It does as advertised and answers the question, however, in my case, the background color appears in the dropdown menu but disappears once the option is selected.

Comment: @Armitage2k: I don't understand. Do you mean it works in the snippet above but doesn't work when you try to apply it to your own code?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it works alright, but the background color is gone once the option has been selected

Comment: @Armitage2k: **Again:** In the snippet above, or in your own code? For me, using the snippet above, the color does not disappear using either Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder in my own code, running on XAMPP (latest) and Chrome 54.0.2840.71 m (64-bit). Either way, I posted a solution with code where I do not meet this issue for everyone's reference.

Comment: @Armitage2k: Updated the above to discuss why it wasn't working in your code but was above, with solutions and options.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder just curious, how can I apply the css to existing select fields? Right now the color only comes up if I select Yes/No from the dropdown menu, but it does not apply on select fields that are populated with a previously selected Yes/No value. eg. if I populate the select's with data from a MySQL table, the color does not apply.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you want to achieve.
I changed your code to:

```
 $('select').on('change', function () {
      $(this).focus();
      $(this).select();
      $(this).css("background-color",$(this).find(":selected").attr("class"));
  });
```

It sets the background color after select based on class name.
Tested on Firefox

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a common class for those select boxes? If you do, you can select them doing this:

```
$(".your_class").on("change", function(){
  $(this).addClass("border_red"); //add border to select
  $("option",this).removeClass("red"); //clear classes
  $("option:selected", this).addClass("red"); //add .red class
});
```

Check out the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m5mzwyt2/

Answer (score 0):

The code below works for me, both in the sense of highlighting the option value in green / red, and to keep the background color once the option has been selected

JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').on('change', function () {
        $(this).focus();
        $(this).select();
        this.className = this.options[this.selectedIndex].className;
    });
});
```